# Extract filename using regex in php

Tags: php, regex

```
<ac:image ac:height="400">
<ri:attachment ri:filename="screenshot4.png"></ri:attachment>
</ac:image>
```

result should be **screenshot4.png**

Comment: I am learning regex and I think it can be done via regex. I can't figure out how?

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

While regular expressions could be used to successfully extract the filename from the XML in its current form, it wouldn't be a correct solution. You cannot parse XML or HTML with regular expressions properly.

Use one of the commonly available PHP extensions: [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) or [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

Below is an example using SimpleXML.

```
$xml = <<<XML
<ac:image ac:height="400">
<ri:attachment ri:filename="screenshot4.png"></ri:attachment>
</ac:image>
XML;

$doc = new SimpleXMLElement($xml, LIBXML_NOERROR);

$filename = (string) $doc->{'ri:attachment'}->attributes()['ri:filename'];

var_dump($filename);
```

**Output:**

> string(15) "screenshot4.png"

No regular expressions needed.

Answer (score -2):

```
[\w]*\.[\w]*
```

Would be an very basic version. Explanation, because you wan´t to learn it:

1. `\w` matches any word char (a-z,A-Z and numerics)
2. `*` quantifier matches zero or more chars
3. `\.` escapes the single dot

So this RegEx looks for a string, containing letters and digits that are followed by a single dot and concluded with another sequence of letters and digits.

Hope that helped...

**EDIT:**

Using a RegEx in your case (XML etc.), could return wrong matches...

Comment: Did you know that \w includes \d?

Comment: Also, did you know that without a quantifier, this regex will only match one character filename with one character extension?

Comment: yes, you´re right. Numerics are contained in \w and about the quantifier, the '*' char was not visible because I´ve missed to mark the RegEx as code ;)